# Postgres SQL - SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "orders__line_items"

Tags: postgresql

I am struggling with the subject error in the query below: it seems the
error is in the line indicated;
I need to specify orders__line_items.id otherwise 'id' is
ambiguous.
I have tried all sorts of combination of brackets, full names etc..

```
SELECT
    orders__line_items.id::character varying AS id,   <-- ERROR SEEMS TO BE HERE
    CAST(orlin.created_at::timestamptz AS date) AS timestamp,
    orlin.price_set__shop_money__amount AS price,
    orlin.quantity AS quantity,
    orlin._sdc_source_key_id as prova,
    orlin.product_id as product_id
  FROM
    (SELECT * FROM orders__line_items
    LEFT JOIN shopify_a100."orders" ON _sdc_source_key_id = 
shopify_a100."orders"."id"
    LEFT JOIN shopify_a100."products" ON "product_id" = 
shopify_a100."products"."id") AS orlin
```

Comment: You essentially aliased `orders__line_items` as `orlin` so use `orlin.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because `orders__line_items` is not recognized by the `SELECT`, you must prepare the selected columns within the subsquery.

If the `id` is the only ambiguous column, here's a solution :

```
SELECT
    orlin.id,
    CAST(orlin.created_at::timestamptz AS date) AS timestamp,
    orlin.price_set__shop_money__amount AS price,
    orlin.quantity AS quantity,
    orlin._sdc_source_key_id as prova,
    orlin.product_id as product_id
FROM (
  SELECT orders__line_items.id,
         created_at,
         price_set__shop_money__amount,
         quantity,
         _sdc_source_key_id,
         product_id
  FROM orders__line_items
  LEFT JOIN shopify_a100."orders" ON _sdc_source_key_id = shopify_a100."orders"."id"
  LEFT JOIN shopify_a100."products" ON "product_id" = shopify_a100."products"."id"
) AS orlin
```